# joomla 2.5 to 3.6 upgrade error

Tags: joomla-3.x, joomla-2.5, update

I updated my joomla site from 2.5 to 3.6 with joomla core update component.

First, I updated joomla 2.5 to last version (2.5.8) and update extensions to last versions. and then update joomla to 3.6

but during updating process shows me below error:

```
Warning: require_once(C:\xampp\htdocs\projectname\libraries/import.legacy.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\projectname\administrator\includes\framework.php on line 15
```

and:

```
Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'C:\xampp\htdocs\projectname\libraries/import.legacy.php' (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\projectname\administrator\includes\framework.php on line 15
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

As per the advice at https://www.joomla.org/announcements/release-news/5666-the-joomla-3-6-1-update.html, Joomla 2.5.x needs to be migrated to 3.5.1 at which point you can use the Joomla Update component to upgrade to 3.6.0 and then 3.6.2 or later.

To migrate Joomla 2.5.x to 3.5.1 specifically, you will probably have to use a manual update process as per https://docs.joomla.org/Updating_Joomla_(Manual_Method) or https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Upgrading_from_Joomla_3.4.x_to_3.5 or similar.

You can find the 3.5.1 release at: https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/releases/download/3.5.1/Joomla_3.5.1-Stable-Full_Package.zip